# How to free the memory that is dynamically allocated by member functions of a Queue class which is implemented by Linked List?

Tags: c++, class, oop, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I implemented a Queue class with linked list, which have the functions **push** and **pop**. The **push** function allocates some memory dynamically with the **new** operator each time is is called. My question is:

1. How to free these memory allocated by the **push** function (assume pop isn't called)? Does the destructor I wrote work?
2. If I were to create a Queue object dynamically by `Queue* queue2 = new Queue();`, will calling `delete queue2` free the memory allocated by **push** function (assume pop isn't called)?

Below is the code I wrote:

```
struct ListNode { 
    ListNode* next;
    int val;
    ListNode(int x) {
        val = x;
        this->next = nullptr;
    }
};

class Queue {
public:
    Queue() {
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
    }
    
    // Destructor for freeing all dynamically allocated memory
    ~Queue(){
        if (head){
            ListNode* cur = head;
            ListNode* next;
            // iterate through the list and free all memory
            while (cur){
                next = cur->next;
                delete cur;
                cur = next;
            }
            head = nullptr;
        }
    }

    void push_front(int x) { // add node at then end of linked list
        // Need to dynamically allocate front bc want it to persist after leaving this block
        ListNode* front = new ListNode(x);
        if (!head) {
            head = front;
            tail = head;
        }
        else {
            tail->next = front;
            tail = tail->next;
        }
    }

    void pop_back() { // remove the first node of the linked list
        if (!head) {
            return;
        }
        ListNode* newHead = head->next;
        delete head; // free memory
        head = newHead;
    }

private:
    ListNode* head;
    ListNode* tail;
};


int main() {
    Queue queue = Queue();
    queue.push_front(1);
    queue.push_front(2);
}
```

Comment: If it was allocated by `new`, delete it with `delete`. If it was allocated by `new[]`, delete it with `delete[]`. You're doing that, and your destructor appears correct. What is your actual question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes normally stuff allocated during the lifetime of the object are de-allocated in the destructor when the object is destroyed.

So answering your first question. Yes the destructor looks like it is doing the correct thing.

---

The unasked question is your code doing enough.
Here the answer is no. The problem is that the compiler generates a couple of methods automatically that do not work well with dynamic allocation, and you have to provide your manually implementation.

So your class is lacking a copy constructor and an copy assignment operator. This is known as **The Rule of Three** (Copy Constructor/Copy Assignment/Destructor).

```
{
    Queue   a;
    a.push_front(1);

    Queue   b(a);   // Problem is here.
                    // The default generated copy constructor
                    // creates a shallow copy of the object.
}
// the destruction of the objects b and a interact resulting in
// a double de-allocation of your ListNode.
```